# Is sha2 hashed field require varchar 32 or 64 field?

Tags: php, mysql, sha256

As I know sha2 generate 256 bit hash.

256bit/8 = 32bytes.

So, It should take only varchar(32) field in the database. But I saw an article saying sah2 database field require varchar(64) field in the database. Is that true? Can someone explain, Please!!

Comment: you don't plan on using this for password storage, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are generally represented as hexadecimal strings:

```
string(64) "316a2017faa1ee410aadfb159097b8af260a258aa4210c550844cab89083111d"
```

In this case, SHA256 is 64 bytes. However, you may choose to store it in its binary form. This will make it take half as much space (32 bytes) but will make it unreadable in your database shell:

```
string(32) "̵9�~Rbgc\�7ME���)Fw�w��E�kc5"
```

Whether you store as a 64 byte string or a 32 byte binary is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, Thai is a grate answer. If you can you give me some reference to read about hash algorithms, I'll thankful for you a lot. (I don't need to understand algorithm(procedure). I just want to know properly input length, output length etc)

Comment: See `hash_algos()`. That will tell you which algorithms are available on your machine. Then run each of those through `hash($algo, 'foo')` to see how big the output is.

Comment: Thanks. But, I have worked with blowfish in php. But, I had to face some issues when my salt is not long enough. So, I read the php.net site. But I could not found any answer. After that I found the reason after long effort!! That's why I asked for appropriate references from person who has the knowledge!!

Comment: 99 times out of 100 plain-text representations are vastly better. Binary data is obnoxious, and nothing frustrates DBAs more than when a `SELECT * FROM table...` type query has so much garbage binary data in it that the terminal gets scrambled because it inadvtertently interprets those as control codes. Hard drives are stupid huge today, even a 1TB drive costs under $80, SSD under $500, so there's almost no reason to make life difficult just to save a handful bytes per row.

Comment: Also `STRING(n)` is not a valid MySQL type. That should be `VARCHAR(n)`.

Comment: @tadman That's not a MYSQL type, that's the output of `var_dump()` -- just intended to show the length, not to be a schema guide.

Answer (score 1):

Use varchar(64) or string(64). You need 64 characters to represent the 256 bits in SHA-256, it's represented in hexadecimal so each digit represents 4 bits and that's 256/4 = 64.